# What mistake is there in my code in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to i Phone programming.In this code i have store images in array that images i have added in bundle,that image i can able to display in thumbnail.Similarly i have create private folder in document directory there i have add 2 images that after that i retrieve that images in array but i am not able display private document directory images in thumbnail but i can able to display bundle images.In below code 2 localImages are there one of the localImages i have store bundle images and one more localImages i have store private document directory folder images.Now bundle images are displaying but i commented that bundle localImages.and i using private document directory images in same localImages that not working its showing some Expection.

```
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tauky"];
     NSLog(@"%@",savedImagePath);
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath])
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:savedImagePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:savedImagePath error:&error];
localImages = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.jpeg'"];
    imagesOnly = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    localImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imagesOnly];
    NSLog(@"%@",localImages);

self.title = @"FGallery";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

localCaptions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"images53", @"image57",nil];
//localImages =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"lava.jpeg",@"hawaii.jpeg",nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",localImagess);
```

Expection is below code

```
- (void)reloadGallery
{
    _currentIndex = _startingIndex;
    _isThumbViewShowing = NO;

    // remove the old
    [self destroyViews];

    // build the new
    if ([_photoSource numberOfPhotosForPhotoGallery:self] > 0) {
        // create the image views for each photo
        [self buildViews];

        // create the thumbnail views
        [self buildThumbsViewPhotos];

        // start loading thumbs
        [self preloadThumbnailImages];

        // start on first image
        [self gotoImageByIndex:_currentIndex animated:NO];

        // layout
        [self layoutViews];
    }
}
```

In console its show like this

```
self=(FGalleryViewController *)0x6877050
    _cmd=(SEL)0x103cf reloadgallery
```

I not getting i tried so many ways what to do.Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You name your method `reloadGallery`, but you seem to be calling it as `reloadgallery` (notice the lowercase 'g'!). Change the call to `reloadGallery` and it should be fine.